# When partitioning the odd and even numbers on the clock such that blocks don't cross, how to show that always 7 blocks are needed?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I want to partition the numbers 1 to 12 on the clock into blocks of numbers such that

1. no block contains both odd and even numbers,
2. no two blocks cross each other,
3. given the blocks of odd numbers, blocks with even numbers should be chosen such that they are of maximal size.

An example of such a partition is graphically represented
by connecting numbers in the same block with lines,
as if a rubber band has been stretched around them:

[image: Partition {{1,7,9},{3},{5},{11},{2,4,6},{8},{10,12}}]

The odd numbers are partitioned into the blocks $\{1,7,9\},\{3\},\{5\}$ and $\{11\}$
and the even numbers are partitioned into the blocks $\{2,4,6\}, \{8\}$ and $\{10,12\}$.
That is seven blocks in total.
Apparently, always seven blocks are needed to partition the numbers 1 to 12
such that the above three rules are satisfied.

**Question:**
How to show this?

I see that when all the odd numbers are put together into one block,
then the even numbers must each individually be put into a separate block:

[image: Partition {{1,3,5,7,9,11},{2},{4},{6},{8},{10},{12}}]

When all the odd numbers but one are put together into one block,
e.g., all but 11,
then the even numbers must each individually be put into a separate block
except for the two that are adjacent to 11, i.e., 10 and 12,
these are put together into one block:

[image: Partition {{1,3,5,7,9},{11},{2},{4},{6},{8},{10,12}}]

But how to proceed and show that in all cases exactly seven blocks are needed?

The problem is not just reserved to the numbers 1 to 12.
Apparently, for any positive integer $n$, to partition the numbers 1 to $2n$ in the above way exactly $n+1$ blocks are needed.
I would be interested to know how to tackle this general case.

This is basically Exercise 9.23(4) in Lectures on the Combinatorics of Free Probability by Nica and Speicher.
The partition of even numbers can be interpreted as the Kreweras complement
of the partition of odd numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get this through "Invariants" :

When we have the numbers $1 \cdots 2n$ , we can put all even numbers in a Block , leaving the remaining numbers in $n$ Blocks , hence we have $n+1$ Blocks.

We can try to change the Blocking via "Short-Circuiting" : what I mean by that is : given $ \cdots A,B,C \cdots $ in some larger Block , we can leave out $B$ to get $ \cdots A,C \cdots $. This is always Possible because the new line is inside the Block Area. This will not Change the Block-Count.

Now , we can "Combine" 2 Blocks to connect $B-1$ & $B+1$ { which were not in Same Block Earlier due to $B$ preventing the Connection } hence putting them in Same Block.
This will Decrease the Block-Count by 1.

Unfortunately , we have left out $B$ which can not connect to other Blocks due to the neighbours.
Hence we have to "Create" a new Block to put $B$ in it. This will Increase the Block-Count by 1.

Over-all , the "Short-Circuiting" + "Combining" + "Creating" gives no Change [ $0-1+1=0$ ] in Block-Count , which is "Invariant".

Hence , Block-Count is always $n+1$.